# Applying CSS (via LESS) to modal box by ID does not work

Tags: css, html, modal-dialog, less

I'm a new user to StackOverflow. Looking forward to be part of your wonderful community. My question is as follows:

I want to use a Twitter Bootstrap modal box on my website. However, I'm facing problems getting the CSS to work on the modal box. I wrote the following HTML code:

```
<div id="playModal" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-header">  
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <span class="login"><strong>Login</strong></span>
</div>  
<div class="modal-body">  
    <form class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="play_form_username">Username</label>
                <div class="controls">  
                    <input type="text" id="play_form_username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="play_form_password">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">  
                    <input type="password" id="play_form_password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required />
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </fieldset> 
        <span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Play!</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>  
<div class="modal-footer">  
    <span>Not a member yet? <a href="#registerModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static">Join Now!</a></span>
    <!--need to find a way to get this modal box to disappear if registerModal is called-->
</div>  
</div>
```

Next, I want to configure the design of the page. I am using LESS to write code which is converted to CSS through SIMPLESS. I tried passing my desired CSS configuration through the modal div ID in the following LESS code:

```
#playModal{
width: 300px;
.modal-backdrop,
.modal-backdrop.fade.in{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.modal-header{
    .login{
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
}
.modal-body{
    max-height: 200px;
}
}
```

This compiles successfully to CSS, but when I analyse the webpage using Firebug, it appears that ***none of the CSS has been passed for the modal box***. Instead, if I use pass the CSS configurations by class, similar to the following, it works.

```
.modal{
width: 315px;
margin-left: 0px;
left: 50%;
top: 58px;
.modal-header{
    padding: 7px 15px;
    .login{
        color: #203665;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        line-height: 24px;

    }
}
}
```

Why is it that the CSS rules are not passed when referring to the modal box by ID? Isn't ID be more specific than class? Note: even when i use !important on the code using ID, it doesn't work.

It will be greatly appreciated if someone can help me out- though it's probably because I did something stupid. (The context why I need to use ID and not just class is: I'm needing to add a second modal box, and I want it to have different size, field sizes etc.) Thanks.

**EDIT: (Answers my own silly question)**
After dabbling around with the code, I found that the following works:

```
//Settings for all models
.modal-backdrop.fade.in{
opacity: 0.9!important;
filter: alpha(opacity=90)!important;
}

//Settings for playModal
#playModal{
width: 315px;
margin-left: 0px;
left: 50%;
top: 58px;
.modal-header{
    padding: 7px 15px;
    .login{
        color: #203665;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        line-height: 24px;

    }
}
.modal-body{
    padding: 10px;
    .control-group{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        .control-label{
            width: 65px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .controls{
            margin-left: 75px;
        }
    }
    span a{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        float: left;
        &:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
    .form-actions{
        display: block;
        float: right;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        .btn{
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 24px;
        }
    }
}
.modal-footer{
    padding: 7px!important;
}
}
```

I think what I did wrong was to put the .modal-backdrop.fade.in inside the #playModal, it dawns on me now that .modal-backdrop.fade-in would be referring to the area ***outside*** of the #playModal div.

So all in all it was just a trivial mistake that got me worked up for so many hours. Sorry to waste everyone's time. What a way to start on StackOverflow. But anyway thanks everyone for trying to help me out. Please vote to close this post.

Comment: Maybe if you try to wrap it instead of giving it an id? make sense?

Comment: Sorry, not too sure what you mean. Anyway, I'm needing to refer to the id in the button to activate the modal box, as follows:         <a href="#playModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static"></a>

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong case.

You give the element the id, `playModal`

Your css refers to `#playmodal`

Css is case-sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. I did use #playModal (correct case) in CSS. Just reran the code to confirm, but once again noticed that as soon as I add the #playModal{} outside in LESS, it's back to the default Twitter Bootstrap settings (not using mine).